# push_back a pointer to a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have two classes: `Item` and `Box`. In `Box.h` I have:

```
class Box {
  vector<const Item *> BoxItems;

   public:
   void AddItem(const Item *i);
}
```

In `Box.cpp`:

```
void Box::AddItem(const Item *i) {
  BoxItems.push_back(*i);
}
```

Just for reference, but in `main.cpp`:

```
box.AddItem(&items[0]);
```

**The problem:** when I compile, I get `error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'`, referencing the `push_back` from the vector I created in `Box.h`. **What I am missing?**

So far, I have tried:

```
void Box::AddItem(const Item *i) {
  this -> BoxItems.push_back(*i);
  Box::BoxItems.push_back(*i);
  BoxItems->push_back(*i);
}
```

But still with the same error.

Comment: `push_back(i);`

Comment: Why do you dereference the pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Box::AddItem(const Item *i) {
  BoxItems.push_back(*i);
}
```

You're calling `push_back` with an `Item` when it's supposed to take a pointer to an `Item`. Change `*i` to `i`.

However, I would strongly suggest not using vectors of pointers because it makes it very difficult to get object ownership right. Instead, consider using vectors of objects, vectors of `unique_ptr`s to objects or vectors of `shared_ptr`s to objects.